# User can log in with old and new passwords

Tags: 12.04, passwd

Running Ubuntu 12.04, I changed the password of a user using

```
sudo passwd user
```

but now that user is able to log in using both the old password and the new password. Any idea of why this would happen?

Comment: Yeah. Use `sudo passwd -d <username>` to delete the password and then retry.

Comment: @kiwijj on which screen / interface does that happen?

Comment: You really should provide additional information - from the mechanism of password checking in linux the exact behavior you described is "not possible". So we have to look at some background. As of now we are fishing in the dark and I have no idea if a proposed solution will work or (just maybe) do even harm.

Answer (score 2):

I made a change to the `common-auth` file located in `/etc/pam.d/` and this has resolved the problem. (I copied over the file from a system that worked to the one that didn't)

Non working file:

```
auth required pam_group.so use_first_pass 
auth [success=3 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass 
auth [success=2 default=ignore] pam_ccreds.so minimum_uid=1000 action=validate use_first_pass 
auth [default=ignore] pam_ccreds.so minimum_uid=1000 action=update
```

Working file:

```
auth required pam_group.so use_first_pass
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
```

Comment: Can you isolate the difference between the two, so we can get an idea which entry/entries caused the issue (e. g. with `diff -Ru /etc/pam.d.old-broken /etc/pam.d`).

Comment: Please edit your post (in this case your question would be preferable, because it's still a description of the original issue), if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset password again...

**Note**: Run below cmd without `sudo`.This changes the password for current user.

```
$ passwd
Enter the new password (minimum of 5, maximum of 8 characters).
Please use a combination of upper and lower case letters and numbers.
Old password: <old password goes here>
New password: <new password goes here>
Re-enter new password: <new password goes here>
Password changed.
```